# imported Java class that doesn't exist

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

I have some basic knowledge of Java. I am currently learning a software called hybris, which is made up of many java projects.

In that software in many classes I see imports of other classes/interface that I can't find. 
For example: I have

`import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.user.interceptors.ModifySystemUsersInterceptor;`

But, when  I go to `de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.user.interceptors` package I can't find that class. I also tried searching for a file with a name: 
`ModifySystemUsersIntercep`, but didn't find anything. Yet, eclipse doesn't display any errors. How is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is packaged into a jar file within the program. Normally, when a developer is using a separate library, it is stored in an external jar file, and then they are linked at compile time. The reason you cannot find the file is because it is within a jar file, which is essentially a zip file full of `.class` files, which are in encoded bytecode. The reason you do not receive errors is because you already have the project set up, with the appropriate libraries linked to the program, which is why eclipse does not return any errors.

Comment: No problem. It can be confusing at first.